# string.Replace(); with two cases? / How to Parse Time strings

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a timePicker that returns to me the time like: "0:00am". But i need in my app to sub a start time from a finish time and check if it has passed one hour, two...

To get only the numbers of the TimePicker, I did this:

```
string StartTime = _pickerStarts.Text;
        string StartTime_int = string.Empty;
        int _starts = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < StartTime.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(StartTime[i]))
                StartTime_int += StartTime[i];
        }

        if (StartTime_int.Length > 0)
            _starts = int.Parse(StartTime_int);


        string EndsTime = _pickerEnds.Text;
        string EndsTime_int = string.Empty;
        int _ends = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < EndsTime.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(EndsTime[i]))
                EndsTime_int += EndsTime[i];
        }

        if (EndsTime_int.Length > 0)
            _ends = int.Parse(EndsTime_int);

        // this return method is returning with the 00 on 4:00AM (example). CHANGE IT.
        return _ends - _starts;
```

But as you can probably guess, instead of returning, for example, 9 from 9:00am, it returns 900. I did this for o'clock hours:

```
string StarTime_Formated = StartTime.Replace(":00", "");
```

And I'd have to do this for :30 hours.

```
string StarTime_Formated = StartTime.Replace(":00", ",3");
```

But then i'd have to check the strings content first to then format it. Is there a way of doing this (pseudo code):

```
string StarTime_Formated = StartTime.Replace(":00", ",3" && ":00", "");
```

**EDIT:** Responding the comments below: Well, the component i'm using returns a string. It's for class time control. One class can be two times a week 1 hour each class or one time  week 2 hours each class. If i do this:

```
if(_numDuration.Value == 2 && ClassDuration() == 2)
```

`ClassDuration()` being the first code in this post and `_numDuration` being a `IntegerUpDown` to select 1 or 2 hours class.

The method will return, for example "4:00pm" and "6:00pm", 600-400, and that's way higher than two. I need it to return 2 instead. As I said, I can do two different `.Replace("", "");` and check each case, but i'm wondering if i can't just `string StarTime_Formated = StartTime.Replace(":00", ",3" && ":00", "");`

I'd use DateTime if I could, but you see, it's not really my app, and... orders. It sucks.

Can I do that, or should I just keep with the two separated `.Replace()` and then check the cases?

Comment: What's wrong with just `if ((endTime - startTime).TotalHours > 1)`, etc.?

Comment: @itsme86 I believe problem is that both are strings

Comment: What?? DateTimePicker has a Value property. It is a DateTime and a DateTime has Minute, Hour, Seconds properties. No need to parse anything

Comment: If you are talking about a WPF TimePicker, then again, there is a Time property that is a TimeSpan and you can use it to get your values or execute calculations against another TimeSpan

Comment: If if you can't use DateTime controls, you can still make the DateTime.Parse() method do all the hard work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve, is how to parse time strings?

It is tricky, and more than a few lines of code to do correctly. let DateTime do it for you?

```
var start= DateTime.Parse(_pickerStarts.Text);
var end= DateTime.Parse(_pickerEnds.Text);
var result= end-start;
var resultInHours= result.TotalHours;
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.WriteLine(resultInHours);
```

————————————————————————————————————————

For string replacing though, you may have a typo in your question. Did you want:

```
string StarTime_Formated = StartTime.Replace(":30", ",3").Replace(":00", "");
```

Comment: Really apreciate the answer, but It's not DateTimes, the ones i'm working with are strings. I'm just wondering if I can do a .Replace() for two different cases in one .Replace() method.

Comment: You noticed that I'm starting with strings?

Comment: So sorry, re-read the answer just now. Will do and check soon if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you may have to adjust the format but this should work)

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(your_start_time_string, "hh:mma", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(your_end_time_string, "hh:mma", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var r = endDate-startDate;
//do further processing on result
```